# Is it possible to have users only be able to send emails from an Organization Wide Address?

Tags: email, permissions, user

I want users to have the ability to send emails (via send email permission), but I only want them to be able to use a Org Wide Address to send them and not their personal email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily implement this with a trigger on `EmailMessage` (assuming that you don't send the email in apex). Maybe create a custom permission (or store the enabled org wide emails on the user object) and check in a trigger, if this particular sender (`UserInfo.getUserId()`) is enabled for the org wide address or the personal sender address.

Check the documentation for `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` ([Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_methods)) to see, how you can retrieve the infos if you send emails from apex and check `EmailMessage` entity ([Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)) to see, how you can retrieve it in the trigger.

Comment: Do you know of any way to do this without apex, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply to create an email validation on the email message object.